# Writing with dry erase marker on Shabbos, is it permitted?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, writing-printing

Trying to figure out if I can use a dry erase marker for recreation and then erase whatever I wrote. Is this allowed?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Gustavo and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11781/472

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is forbidden to write, even temporarily on Shabbos. R Jack Abramowitz from OU [writes](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/the-39-melachos/melacha32/)

> Koseiv [writing] involves creating any meaningful letter or symbol.
>   **It doesn’t have to be with ink on paper.** A rubber stamp, carving into stone or cutting a letter out of paper all involve koseiv. **Even
>   forming a letter out of something temporary** – such as those toys
>   where one uses a magnet to manipulate iron filings – **is prohibited
>   on Shabbos** under this melacha. Koseiv applies to letters or symbols
>   in any language, including Braille, Morse code and the like. [...]
>   **Temporary writing is prohibited rabbinically.**

See also [here](http://www.torahlab.org/calendar/article/kosev_writing_on_shabbos/) and [Rambam Hilchot Shabbat 11:9](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/935218/jewish/Shabbat-Chapter-Eleven.htm).