# Operating a mechanical calculator on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, mitzvah, shiurim-measurements, muktzeh

Are mechanical calculators Mukzte on Shabbos? Would it be considered a form of measuring?

Mechanical calculators have no electric parts. Everything is purely mechanical:

[image: Mechanical Calculator]

If it *is* considered measuring, then what about using a mechanical tally to keep track of something?

[image: Mechanical Tally Counter]

And finally, does this all depend on if the measuring is done for a Mitzvah?

Comment: It is very likely *uvdin d'chol* (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/96170/11501)) and/or forbidden because it might lead to doing business

Comment: חפציך בו אסורים וגם לחשוב מחשבות...

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11762/games-on-shabas-that-involve-writing-whose-writing