# What game is the Rama in 338:5 (טשי"ך) referring to?

Tags: shabbat, words, shulchan-aruch, games-toys

In the English Mishna Brurah they translate טשי"ך as chess. The Mishna Brurah brings the Marah Sasson who forbids it because there is no *chachma*. It is also mentioned in the Rama that it makes noise, and as far as I know chess does not involve noise? Also, the Aruch Hashulchan says the pieces hit each other, he also gives another name for the game (מייליסקע"ס, seems similar to kugalach) not sure if it translates as chess. The Magen Avraham gives yet another name for the game. So, which game does the Rama refer to?

A side point: The gemarah in [Kesubas 61b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=61b&format=pdf) names a game and Rashi calls it chess with the name אישקקי"ש. The common Hebrew name for chess today is שחמט.

Comment: http://torahmusings.com/2013/05/chess-in-jewish-law/

Comment: in russian chess is called shahHmati(i is not ee but closer to i in him). this could be a reason why chess is called shahHmat today. http://translate.google.com/#en/ru/chess you can listen here how it is pronounced.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob, the name _shachmat_ appears in many languages, all deriving ultimately from Persian/Farsi (or one of its ancestors, like Old Persian. I don't know how old Persian, or this word, is). English _chess_ derives from Persian _shah_ ("king"), the etymon of half of _shachmat_. I wouldn't be surprised if the _Rama_'s _tshich_ does, too, just based on how it looks, but that's a guess.

Comment: @msh210 shahH means check and mat means mate in russian.shahHmat means check mate.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob, or maybe "checkmate" is an English derivative of шахматы.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob, SethJ, _checkmate_ also comes from Persian and is cognate to other languages' _shachmat_. _Check_ is from Persian _shah_.

Comment: @msh210, that's more or less what I mean - шахматы doesn't derive from the English.  Whatever the direct source, Russian or Persian, English derived it from another language, not the other way around.

Comment: Your idea about [kugelach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knucklebones) is correct. It was historically played with [טשי"ך bones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talus_bone) (perhaps that's why the game is commonly called "jacks"). Several early acharonim discuss this bone in the context of *hilchos t'reifos*. Also, the term used by the *Aruch HaShulchan* sounds kind of like the Lithuanian for "[malleolus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleolus) of the ankle".

Comment: The name mentioned in the shiltei giborim is בריקיקלי. He lived in Italy.

Comment: Where is this Shiltei Gibborim?

Comment: @user6591 That's possibly related to the modern word for a "knucklebone" in Dutch ("bikkel") or West Flemish ("pekkel"). This *Shiltei Giborim* is in *Eruvin* ([35b in *dapei haRif*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37954&st=&pgnum=405), אות ג).

Comment: @Fred Nice. A quick search for a polish version of knucklebones/marbles came up with szklana kulka. That's pretty close to the Ramma's word.

Comment: @user6591 "Szklane kulki" does mean "glass marbles/beads" in Polish (although "[marmurki](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marmurki)" is the standard term for marbles in Polish). However, games with glass marbles were developed in the 19th century, postdating the Rama, who was talking about a game played with bones (which is how kugelach was historically played).

Comment: @Fred well i didn't mean it's the same exact item. Just a similar name for a similar game.

Comment: @Fred oh no. Slip of the thumb. I meant the shilei hagiborim's word.

Comment: @Fred but he was Italian so there goes my theory

Comment: @user6591 I also considered בריקיקלי as a corruption of [alquerque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alquerque), but mention of bones points more to knucklebones. The *S"G* explicitly discusses chess ("שקאק") in a quote from the *Or Zarua'* later in אות ג. Apparently on this basis, the *Magen Avraham* ([338:8](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa/oc_x1616.pdf)) interprets טשי"ך as chess, although the Rama's mention of "עצמות שקורין טשי"ך" suggests (IMHO) he is citing the earlier part of the *S"G* about "העצמות שקורין בריקיקלי". Also, other early *acharonim* describe the טשי"ך as the astragalus bone.

Comment: @user6591 Also, maybe the *S"G* was referring to tabula or backgammon, considering his phrasing: "וא״כ אסור לשחוק
 באותן העצמות שקורין בריקיקלי ע״ג טבלא", since apparently dice were historically [also made from talus bones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice#History). Then again, maybe both the *S"G* and the Rama weren't talking about any specific game, but just about playing with dice in general (and mention of a טבלא was only relevant due to noise). (And, to correct my previous comment, the *S"G* wasn't quoting the *Or Zarua'* when he mentioned chess).

Comment: @Fred "Also, other early acharonim describe the טשי"ך as the astragalus bone." Can you please show me which acharonim you found that describe טשיך as the talus bone? You seem to be extremely knowledgeable in the area!

Comment: I would appreciate if you can provide the references.

Comment: @Bach See, for example, Bach, Shach, and Taz on YD 55-56 (also citing earlier discussion from Rabbeinu Yerucham, the Rosh, and the Mordechai), and Maharshal on Chullin (4:11-12).

Comment: @Fred wow I posted that question like months ago! In any case, I'll be sure to check out these references. Thanks for getting back!

Answer (score 5):

In the Dirshu Mishna Berura (based on the "Leshem") print, it is translated in a footnote as a game similar to "חמש אבנים" (lit. five stones) - when I was a kid it was called kuglach. It's similar to the game of jacks.